# Why do we need to rebuild to update the error list in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with 4 projects, 3 in C# and 1 in VB, and while Visual Studio 2010 catches basic syntax errors in real time, many other errors do not disappear once they are fixed, but until I rebuild the solution.

With pure VB solutions I had never seen this behaviour.

Your insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 But I've worked with 2010.

Syntax errors are a lot easier to catch and this is done in not only 2010, but 2008 as well. If you're missing a semicolon or a bracket, the text EDITOR is pointing it out for you. The error list is something that the compiler is telling you to fix. Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't have real-time capabilities. (that'd be too cool.)

The editor is taking care of basic syntax errors (which is do-able in real time) but logical errors or implicit casts cannot be detected until you go through it with the compiler. It's not really much of a reason of why you need to rebuild to update the list, you always rebuild. It's the only way you know for sure that you've fixed the error or not. I find myself habitually pressing: ctrl+s, f6, f5.

I hope this answers your question a bit, there is nowhere that explicitly says why you need to rebuild to update the error list, but that's just the way it is. ^^

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks tf.rz. This confirms that I am not alone to observe this, then, but I would be curious to know why we almost never need to rebuild when programming in VB (even for cast errors).


Of course, I don't expect the editor to highlight logical errors, as it is another field (and a very promising one, with interesting papers that could already be implemented an in the IDE).


But it should be able to do all necessary checks in the background to update in real time the compilation error list. This worked fine when doing pure VB, I am wondering why it doesn't seem to be as efficient in C#.

Comment: @Erwin Mayer, You're very welcome. I know what you mean: you'd expect C# to be... more advanced, coming a half-step up from C++, which is already one step up from C. But, if Microsoft were to mimic VB in C# terms of background checks and update the errorlist in real-time, would we really need a compile button at all? Microsoft could easily implement a clocked compiler that compiles every 3 seconds, but that seems inefficient to me. Especially when most programmers spend their time thinking (something I should do more often) rather than physically coding. =)